# JSP does not find resources when changing URL request mapping

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, jetty

I have a SpringMVC JSP that is working nicely, deployed to Jetty. It contains many scripts, css, etc that it loads from the war. I am testing it in Chrome latest version.

My context root is defined as /MYFIRM/myapplication.

Now we have a business requirement to map some but not all of the jsps to /MYFIRM/admin/myapplication/ (adding the admin portion)

All of those JSP's are in a single controller, where I have added

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/admin")
```

Now, the page source loads fine, but it cannot find the scripts and other resources.

The resources are defined like:
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<c:url value='/css/demo.css'/>">
and
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/common/UndoBuffer.js"></script>

When I look at the page source, it has the admin in the resource urls.

Now, I have tried adding a resource mapping to my servlet xml

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/admin/js/**" location="/js/" />
<mvc:resources mapping="/admin/css/**" location="/css/" />
```

But that is not working. In fact, when I look at the page source, the admin is gone, and when I click on the URLs embedded in the page source (admin is correctly removed) It loads up the correct resource in a browser window.

But when I look at the developer console, it still shows admin in the urls and gives me an error.

I have tried moving my resources to a new child directory called admin and that works, but there are other issues with that

Does anyone have any ideas what I might be missing?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem (web app deployed on Tomcat). What worked for me was adding the static resources to my web.xml

```
 <servlet-mapping>
 <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
 <url-pattern>*.css</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
```

Note that default means that the default servlet should handle the static resource(s).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It didn't work for our Jetty deployment but I am sure Tomcat users will benefit from your answer